# How to terminate standard input?

Tags: windows, stdin, rust

In C++, I can read from stdin like this:

```cpp
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    process(line);
```

when I enter Ctrl+Z (Windows),  it terminates standard input, and the loop ends. I can do something similar in other languages.

I tried to translate the idiom to Rust, and I came up with this:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    loop {
        match io::stdin().read_line() {
            Ok(line) => process(line),
            Err(_) => break,
        }
    }
}

fn process(x: String) {
    println!("{:?}", x.as_bytes());
}
```

However, when I do Ctrl+Z when running this code, it does not go to the Err case. It just processes the line as Ok. Giving a string with 3 characters, the SUB character (0x1A), followed by CRLF (`"\r\n"`).

So, how do I terminate standard input and cause `read_line` to fail? Or rather, how do I detect the request for termination of standard input? I can check for the SUB character, but that is not portable, as it would be a different character (e.g. EOT) on other systems.

**Edit**

There is an open issue for this on the github repo. [Issue #19914](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19914)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my Windows VM handy to test this, but it works on OS X (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>). Does this work in your case:

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn process(a: &str) {}

fn main() {
    for line in stdin().lock().lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(line) => process(&*line),
            Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it does not. Does my version work for you on OS X? (and would you expect it to? I'm fairly new to Rust)

Comment: Your code does work on OS X. It's strange, because I'm certain I've done this before on a Windows version of Rust. The version I presented is a bit more idiomatic, as the EOF is handled by the iterator and so you only have to think about "true" error conditions. If no one else chimes in, I'll be able to get to my Windows VM in a few hours...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, your program works for me on OS X. `Ctrl-D` finishes it. `Ctrl-D` closes the standard input which makes `lines()` return `IoError` with `ErrorKind::EndOfFile`, so yes, I would expect that this code should work.

Comment: Yep, this only seems to be a problem on Windows (or at least, my Windows). I fired up my own Ubuntu VM and it works fine.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character) the UNIX terminal processes the control-D and signals EOF on standard input.  That's probably the same in OS X, so this isn't something Rust itself is doing.  On Windows, the C runtime library processes control-Z if you are reading in text mode and treats it as EOF, but from a brief search through the source code for the Rust runtime library, I think it uses the Win32 console functions on Windows rather than the C runtime.  So I fear that on Windows a Rust programmer may have to handle control-Z explicitly.